# Make this query faster?

Tags: sql, firebird

```
SELECT num, code, LN AS LabelName
FROM product 
INNER JOIN link
  ON product.seqno = link.seqno
INNER JOIN master
  ON link.code = master.code
```

Like is there any other way to write this SQL?

```
DB layout is like this:

1)TABLE: product
num(key)
ln
seqno

2)TABLE: link
seqno(key)
code(key)

3)Table: master
code(key)
```

Comment: optimizing sql queries starts with analyzing why they are slow. in IBExpert there is query PLAN shown and also there is a chart of operations like disk fetches, cache fetches and so (those numbers and plan you are to read yourself and to put in the question for us to read as well). You should read those and see what is the bottleneck. Also IBExpert has "script" tab for every table showing its declaration - please include those scripts entirely for those three tables you use. PS: a lot of articles about making Firebird queries faster: http://ibase.ru/develop.htm#performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually use the master table

```
select num,code, LN as LabelName  
from product 
inner join link on product.seqno = link.seqno
```

of course you might have taken that part out of your question -- but then how can we answer?

(NB, as written your query might get different results as only codes in the master table would be returned.  I believe this is not why it was linked)

Answer (score 1):

As written, the query will not run because the column `code` is ambiguous -- it could come from either the `master` table or the `link` table.

Assuming that you are not using the `master` table for filtering, then you can remove it from the query:

```
select product.num, link.code, product.LN as LabelName
from product inner join
     link on product.seqno = link.seqno;
```

Otherwise, the query and indexes look reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

is there an index on product.seqno?

depending on the size of the table this could speed up the query significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you talked of *master-detail*, the concept typical for ISAM databases and implying manual management of records locating, I would make a guess you actually needed only ONE set of records, not all the whole database read. Depending on what you needed then it would go like

```
SELECT product.num, link.code, product.LN AS LabelName
FROM product , master , link 
WHERE product.seqno = link.seqno
  AND link.code = master.code
  AND master.ID = 12345
```

or even

```
SELECT product.num, link.code, product.LN AS LabelName
FROM product , master , link 
WHERE product.seqno = link.seqno
  AND link.code = 12345
```

And since you mentioned Delphi you should replace 12345 with parameters like shown at http://bobby-tables.com/delphi.html